# How to design a Ruler in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I want to design a ruler as shown in the image below:

[image]

Which approach is the best possible way to design a ruler with these small and big lines(scale divisions) as shown in the image.
Also text and numbers will be added with the scale divisions.

There is one knob which i can slide from left to right and vice versa. Can this be achieved using Slider component?

Comment: You can draw a scale on the background of a Slider, but that's not a built-in functionality. You have to add it.

Comment: There is no such built-in control so you have to create your one by extending either `QQuickItem` (OpenGL) or `QQuickPaintedItem` (QPainter), QML makes it easy. Also you can do that using `Canvas` if performance is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the QtQuick.Extras module it has a [Gauge QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-extras-gauge.html). For tick marks use the tickmark and minorTickmark properties from the GaugeStyle QML Type. Then add to this what you want.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "gray"
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2

    Gauge {
        minimumValue: 0
        value: 50
        maximumValue: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. But this is not what i was expecting. Definitely i will try to explore more about Gauge.

Answer (score 1):

```
Item {
            
            width: parent.width
            height: 8
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            property real spacing: 33.3

            Repeater {
                model: parent.width / (parent.spacing + 1) - 1
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    x: index * (rowLayout.spacing + 4)
                    y: parent.height - height
                    implicitWidth: major ? 2  : 1
                    implicitHeight: major ? 18 : 9
                    color: "grey"

                    readonly property bool major: index % 6 == 0
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly customize the `Slider` in `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`. Here is a start for you

```
Slider {
    id: control
    width: parent.width
    height: 50

    background: Canvas {
        x: control.leftPadding + (control.horizontal ? handle.width * 0.5 : (control.availableWidth - width) / 2)
        y: control.topPadding + (control.horizontal ? (control.availableHeight - height) / 2 : 0)
        implicitWidth: control.horizontal ? 200 : control.width
        implicitHeight: control.horizontal ? control.height : 200
        width: control.horizontal ? control.availableWidth - handle.width : implicitWidth
        height: control.horizontal ? implicitHeight : control.availableHeight - handle.height

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

            ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.4)
            ctx.lineWidth = 1

            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(width, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(width, height)
            ctx.lineTo(0, height)
            ctx.lineTo(0, 0)
            for(var x=0;x < width;x += 40) //assuming 40 is unit of measurement
            {
                ctx.moveTo(x, height)
                if(x % 120 == 0)
                    ctx.lineTo(x, height * 0.3)
                else
                    ctx.lineTo(x, height * 0.6)
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    handle: Canvas {
        id: handle
        x: control.leftPadding + (control.horizontal ? control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth - width) : 0)
        y: control.topPadding + (control.horizontal ? 0 : control.visualPosition * (control.availableHeight - height))
        implicitWidth: control.height
        implicitHeight: 28

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

            ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.4)
            ctx.fillStyle = "white"
            ctx.lineWidth = 1

            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(width, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(width, height - width * 0.5)
            ctx.lineTo(width * 0.5, height)
            ctx.lineTo(0, height - width * 0.5)
            ctx.lineTo(0, 0)

            ctx.fill()
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

Part of the code was taken from QtQuick.Controls.Material. I only tested the horizontal slider, vertical will fail (especially the handle)

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I have tried and was able to customize slider as shown below: